# weak and strong convergence proof question

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I am looking over a solution from my hw last semester. I was wondering if the y that I highlighted should be $x_0$?

If it is supposed to be y, can someone explain to me why it isn't $x_0$?

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: Of course it should be $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the confirmation. Just wanting to make sure I understand :)